# What predictions of Bhavisya Purana have come true yet?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhavishya-purana

Bhavisya Purana mentions the future predictions including Kalki avatar. As it has more than 14000 slokas, what are the predictions among them that have come true yet?

Comment: There can be many such predictions. So, your Q might be closed as "too broad". Btw welcome to our site!

Comment: @Rickross What if the OP rephrase as **How much % came true yet**?

Comment: I don't know. But even to calculate that we will need to calculate how many predictions had come true. And there can be many such @hanugm